# How to replace specific strings between two strings in php

Tags: php, mysql, regex, string, replace

I would like to generate sql from this template :

```
select * from event where 
status_id = 'TOREPLACE_1' 
or status_id = 'TOREPLACE_2'
....
```

to have this result :

```
select * from event where 
status_id = (select id from name = 'TOREPLACE_1' limit 1)
or status_id = (select id from name = 'TOREPLACE_2' limit 1)
.....
```

the question is how to select the expression between **''** after every **status_id =**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following regexp:

```
/status_id\s*=\s*\'([^\']+)\'/
```

The whole solution would require something like that:

```
preg_match_all($regexp, $string, $matches);
```